# Como eu faço um condicional usando apenas usando o MÊS da data e a partir dela inserir uma fórmula em uma certa célula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou otimizando uma planilha, porém não está dando certo essa fórmula `=SE($A2="/01/";$S2="=MÊS($A2)";"errado")`. Eu gostaria que a fórmula fizesse o seguinte, caso na célula `A2` conter o mês de janeiro (independente do dia e ano) insira na célula `S2` a fórmula `=MÊS(A2)`, caso de errado insira `ERRADO`, porém na célula `A2` da minha planilha contém a data `12/01/2018`, porém ele esta retornando na célula `S2` o valor "ERRADO".

Answer (score 0):

A sua sintaxe da fórmula `=SE()` está errada.

Insira a seguinte fórmula em `S2`:

`=SE($A2="";"";SE(MÊS($A2)=1;TEXTO(MÊS($A2);"mmmm");"errado"))`

A função `=MÊS()` retorna o mês de uma data em formato numérico, então é necessário converter para o mês em texto com a função `=TEXTO()`.

E quando a célula está vazia, o Excel entende que é janeiro, então é necessário adicionar uma condicional para verificar se a célula `A2` está vazia.